# css expand div in middle of two divs push them to sides

Tags: css

How can this be achived ? I tried using inline-block , but the siblings move to the new line , i want the divs to move to the sides , any hints ?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/CdE2y/

hover the middle div.

Comment: are you allowed to use javascript?

Comment: Are you asking how to achieve something that already works in the fiddle?

Comment: @haxxxton no not really , want to keep best performance

Comment: @D.Kasipovic would you please read my question ! Thank you

Comment: So you want the light blue div to remain on the right side when you slide over dark blue div? You just want it smaller?

Comment: i want it to remain in the row , not to go below the line.

Comment: @ProllyGeek did you want this to move both to the sides? if thats the case have a look at my `justified` solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the divs are `inline-block`, so to prevent them from going to the next line, try setting the `white-space` to `nowrap` for the `container`:

```
#container {
  ...
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CdE2y/2/)

Comment: how can this work so that the first div on left side move too , cause when i have tried to modify left attribute of mid div , it just hovered the first one !

Comment: @ProllyGeek looks like you have new requirement, I'm not sure exactly what you want but I think to move the left div (or do anything with it) from the `:hover` action on the mid div is not possible **with just CSS**, it's because there is no selector helping us to go back to the first div from the second/mid div. You can use script instead or if you want a CSS solution, I think you have to change your layout and tweak it much more (some kind of hack)... So why not add a little script to make it work, here is the updated fiddle with a little script added http://fiddle.jshell.net/CdE2y/6/

Comment: Note that, the script I used in the updated fiddle is `jQuery`, you should learn about it, although pure javascript is OK.

Comment: thanks king , already realised so before you post it , and had to use a script to modify the left attribute of first div to be nagative , thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

What about keeping everything full and centered?

this uses a little trick that comes from the `justified` list items rule from http://getbootstrap.com/ and using `li` instead of `div`

```
<ul id="container">
    <li id="div1">
        <p>Col 1</p>
    </li>
    <li id="div2">
        <p>Col 2</p>
    </li>
    <li id="div3">
        <p>COl 3</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/CdE2y/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/CdE2y/

I changed `inline-block` to `table-cell` and apply `:hover` on `#container`.

Comment: no this is not what i want , i want the cyan div pushed to side but to stay on screen , try for example on hove set width to 37% , the cyan disappears , because it goes to a new row , i want it to stay inline.